nginx config for phpldapadmin
I am trying to setup nginx and phpldapadmin
I keep getting ..\templates\login.php not found (404)
I did a git clone into \usr\share\phpldapadmin and also chown to www-data
This is what I have so far ...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ldap.example.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /usr/share/phpldapadmin;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}


do u hv this file on this path.   /usr/share/phpldapadmin/templates/login.php
